# How to instantatiate struct from the string representation of the struct name

Tags: go

Does go allow you to instantiate a struct from a string? (similar to [ruby convert class name in string to actual class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464007/ruby-convert-class-name-in-string-to-actual-class) in Ruby)

I am trying to separate code from a single file into subdirectories but was getting `undefined: PngConverter` when running `go build`. It may have been a load order issue however now I'm trying to dynamically instantiate the struct.

#### convert_image.go

```
var converters = map[string]string{
  "png": "PngConverter",
  "jpg": "JpegConverter",
  "jpeg": "JpegConverter",
}

type Converter interface {
  convert(*bytes.Buffer) string
}

func selectConverter(converterName string) {
  // dynamically initialize the converter with reflect?
}

func ConvertImageToWords(filename string, image *bytes.Buffer) string {
  ext = Ext(filename)
  if converterName, y := converters[ext]; y {
    converter = selectConverter(converterName)
    id = converter.convert(image)
  }

  return nil
}
```

#### `converters/png_converter.go`

```
type PngConverter struct {}

func (converter PngConverter) convert(in *bytes.Buffer) string {
  // ...
}
```

#### `converters/jpeg_converter.go`

```
type JpegConverter struct {}

func (converter JpegConverter) convert(in *bytes.Buffer) string {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Duplicate. Use a registry like package image does.

Comment: @Volker The image package doesn't identify objects in an image the same way that deep learning does.

Comment: Yes, this is true. And has nothing to do with my comment which is about how to allow different packages to register type into a other packages registry (map from string to actual objects/function/methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't initialize a struct from String representations.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030884/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-a-struct-from-a-string)

What you can do is pass the interface in `ConvertImageToWords`.

```
func ConvertImageToWords(conv Converter, image *bytes.Buffer) string
```

Or have the filename converted to interface `Converter` within `ConvertImageToWords`.

```
func GetConverter(ext string) Converter {
  switch ext {
    case "png":
      return PngConverter{}
    case "jpg":
   ...
}

func ConvertImageToWords(filename string, image *bytes.Buffer) string {
  ext = Ext(filename)
  conv := GetConverter(ext)
  id := conv.convert(image)
  ...
}
```

Also it's better to have the interface method exported :

```
type Converter interface {
  Convert(*bytes.Buffer) string
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181271/is-it-possible-to-implement-an-interface-with-unexported-methods-in-another-pack)

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting `undefined: PngConverter` again since `PngConverter` is in a different file. Is there a way to import `PngConverter` into the main file?

Comment: @Steve Is the file in a different directory ? In go, different directories are separate packages, files within the same directory can use each other's types directly. [Refer](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization)

Comment: Yes, they're in a separate directories: `converters/png_converter.go`, `converters/jpg_converter.go`, `converters/webm_converter.go`

Comment: @Steve You need to go through the [link](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library) I referenced earlier, since your problem is beyond the scope of this answer / comments. You need to familiarise yourself with how Go Development is done.

Answer (score 1):

#### Dynamic evaluation

Go is compiling language it means there is no dynamic evaluation, everything is done after compilation. Interpreting languages like Ruby, Python or Javascript has `eval` (and analogs) functions for dynamic programming which is conceptually impossible for compiling languages.

#### Interfaces as an idiomatic way of abstraction

If you need a generic type in Go - use interface <strike>with no doubt</strike>. Also you are very close to a correct approach: you don't need to evaluate a struct from string instead of it you should declare a map of object of `Converter interface` types with all required implementations.

[Compilable playground](https://play.golang.org/p/avO12K9N0i):

```
var converters map[string]Converter

type Converter interface {
    convert(*bytes.Buffer) string
}

type PngConverter struct{}
type JpgConverter struct{}

func (p *PngConverter) convert(b *bytes.Buffer) (repr string) { return }
func (p *JpgConverter) convert(b *bytes.Buffer) (repr string) { return }

func ConvertImageToWords(
        filename string,
        image *bytes.Buffer,
        converters map[string]Converter) (repr string) {
    ext := Ext(filename)
    if converter, y := converters[ext]; y {
        repr = converter.convert(image)
    }

    return
}
```

#### Import and packages

You haven't been asked but this is wrong design:

> Yes, they're in a separate directories...

Package is a namespace where you can have multiple files and you don't need to import each of them to another. Package is a directory with go files containing `package <name>` as a first line. But if you separated files with different packages (directories) you need to import it if you need to use it in another package. Java-like class-module design is not correct for Go. Just keep all your converters and the interface in the same package.